# Android studio freezing Fedora (nouveau and kernel crash)

Tags: fedora, nvidia, kernel-panic, nouveau

Since the last upgrade to Android Studio (Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000), I am experiencing frequent global system freezes in Fedora 33. Nothing responding, even the SSH server, so the only solution is a hard reboot. It always freezes while typing.

In there anyone here with the same problem?

**EDIT**

By request, I'm adding the output of  `dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,warn`. I hope the information needed is still there:

```
[    0.165884] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.165948]  #5 #6 #7
[    0.172490] pmd_set_huge: Cannot satisfy [mem 0xf8000000-0xf8200000] with a huge-page mapping due to MTRR override.
[    0.173015] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.287753] wait_for_initramfs() called before rootfs_initcalls
[    4.213705] systemd-sysv-generator[573]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys-late' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    4.214895] systemd-sysv-generator[573]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/network' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    4.216144] systemd-sysv-generator[573]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    4.899093] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\PMIO) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.899732] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C40-0x0000000000001C4F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.900844] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.901495] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.901500] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL)
[    4.902664]  (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.902704] ACPI Warning: 
[    4.903893] SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.903896] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    5.178789] at24 13-0050: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.179916] at24 13-0051: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.181186] at24 13-0052: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.182506] at24 13-0053: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.459435] kauditd_printk_skb: 96 callbacks suppressed
[    5.740341] ext4 filesystem being mounted at /boot supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    7.154729] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1005 tx timeout
[    9.202670] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c23 tx timeout
[   11.250636] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[   13.298596] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c25 tx timeout
[   15.346559] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c38 tx timeout
[   17.394520] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
[ 1832.091017] IRQ 29: no longer affine to CPU4
[ 1832.093063] IRQ 28: no longer affine to CPU5
[ 1832.093066] IRQ 30: no longer affine to CPU5
[ 1832.094878] IRQ 23: no longer affine to CPU6
[ 1832.094882] IRQ 25: no longer affine to CPU6
[ 1832.094885] IRQ 32: no longer affine to CPU6
[ 1832.096684] IRQ 18: no longer affine to CPU7
[ 1832.096687] IRQ 19: no longer affine to CPU7
[ 1832.096690] IRQ 27: no longer affine to CPU7
[ 1834.430082] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c16 tx timeout
[ 1836.478094] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2002 tx timeout
[ 1837.499045] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 1837.500053] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 1838.525986] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 1840.574009] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x201c tx timeout
[ 1842.495776] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
[18453.352264] IRQ 29: no longer affine to CPU4
[18453.354087] IRQ 23: no longer affine to CPU5
[18453.354091] IRQ 25: no longer affine to CPU5
[18453.355958] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU6
[18453.355963] IRQ 26: no longer affine to CPU6
[18453.355967] IRQ 32: no longer affine to CPU6
[18453.357790] IRQ 19: no longer affine to CPU7
[18453.357796] IRQ 28: no longer affine to CPU7
[18453.357799] IRQ 30: no longer affine to CPU7
[18455.781051] done.
[18457.872004] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[18458.761887] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[18458.762881] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[18459.919872] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1009 tx timeout
```

**EDIT 2**

It just crashed again. Output of `dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,warn`:

```
[    0.165915] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.165973]  #5 #6 #7
[    0.172521] pmd_set_huge: Cannot satisfy [mem 0xf8000000-0xf8200000] with a huge-page mapping due to MTRR override.
[    0.173044] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.287783] wait_for_initramfs() called before rootfs_initcalls
[    7.086711] usb 3-5: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[    8.324313] kauditd_printk_skb: 5 callbacks suppressed
[    8.940835] systemd-sysv-generator[574]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys-late' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    8.942438] systemd-sysv-generator[574]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/network' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    8.944077] systemd-sysv-generator[574]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    9.619007] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\PMIO) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    9.619640] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C40-0x0000000000001C4F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    9.621931] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    9.622116] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    9.623233] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    9.624779] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    9.625544] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    9.786915] at24 13-0050: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    9.789823] at24 13-0051: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    9.791691] at24 13-0052: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    9.793324] at24 13-0053: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.174554] ext4 filesystem being mounted at /boot supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[   13.354089] kauditd_printk_skb: 87 callbacks suppressed
```

**EDIT 3**

I've experienced around 10 freezes in a couple of days. I'm afraid Studio is going to harm my computer. Freezing continues despite that I upgraded the whole system to the last Fedora 34.

Last output of `dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,warn`:

```
[    0.166421] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.166484]  #5 #6 #7
[    0.173036] pmd_set_huge: Cannot satisfy [mem 0xf8000000-0xf8200000] with a huge-page mapping due to MTRR override.
[    0.173550] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.287346] wait_for_initramfs() called before rootfs_initcalls
[    3.397929] systemd-sysv-generator[567]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys-late' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    3.399641] systemd-sysv-generator[567]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/network' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    3.400982] systemd-sysv-generator[567]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
[    3.713080] systemd-journald[593]: File /var/log/journal/9ff77e59cfd04f078e4b747742c5981e/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[    4.036564] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\PMIO) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.037179] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C40-0x0000000000001C4F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.038257] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.038808] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.039932] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.041794] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[    4.042527] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    4.468471] at24 13-0050: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.470405] at24 13-0051: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.474870] at24 13-0052: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.476069] at24 13-0053: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.637421] ext4 filesystem being mounted at /boot supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    5.321533] kauditd_printk_skb: 100 callbacks suppressed
```

**EDIT 4**
Another freeze. journalctl output of the kernel crash:

```
$ journalctl -S '2021-09-16 13:30:00'

13:43:57 Orion kernel: general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x108ddb743acd5eb1: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CPU: 4 PID: 2724 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 5.13.15-200.fc34.x86_64 #1
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8700/0KWVT8, BIOS A07 03/13/2014
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xac/0x220
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Code: aa 20 d1 44 49 8b 00 49 83 78 10 00 48 89 44 24 08 0f 84 43 01 00 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 3a 01 00 00 8b 4d 28 48 8b 7d 00 48 01 c1 <48> 8b 19 48 89 ce 48>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb7d901f3f700 EFLAGS: 00010206
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RAX: 108ddb743acd5e81 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 108ddb743acd5eb1
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RDX: 0000000000728bcf RSI: 0000000000000dc0 RDI: 00000000000300c0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RBP: ffff8dd200042600 R08: ffff8dd50ed300c0 R09: 0000000000000018
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R10: ffff8dd12d26f208 R11: ffffb7d901f3f988 R12: 0000000000000dc0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R13: ffff8dd200042600 R14: 0000000000003000 R15: ffffffffc06922ce
13:43:57 Orion kernel: FS:  00007f32b7bcea80(0000) GS:ffff8dd50ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CR2: 00007f32b778d000 CR3: 000000010984e003 CR4: 00000000001706e0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Call Trace:
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_mem_new_type+0xae/0x2a0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_umem_new+0x130/0x220 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_ioctl_new+0x129/0x1e0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_umem_search+0xe0/0xe0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0xdc/0x180 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvif_object_ctor+0x122/0x1c0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvif_mem_ctor_type+0xc2/0x180 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_ptes_get_map+0x2c/0x90 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_map+0x18d/0x350 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_mem_host+0xf3/0x190 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_sgdma_bind+0x30/0x80 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_bo_move+0x3c1/0x820 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? ttm_pool_type_take+0x7d/0x90 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? ttm_pool_alloc+0xe6/0x590 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x90/0x170 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_validate+0x11c/0x150 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_init_reserved+0x239/0x2c0 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_init+0x4a/0xc0 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nv10_bo_put_tile_region.isra.0+0x80/0x80 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_bo_init+0x7c/0x90 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nv10_bo_put_tile_region.isra.0+0x80/0x80 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nouveau_gem_new+0xf0/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_gem_new+0x7f/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_gem_ioctl_new+0x45/0xe0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nouveau_gem_new+0xf0/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0x86/0xd0 [drm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x220/0x3e0 [drm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nouveau_gem_new+0xf0/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? __ia32_sys_timer_getoverrun+0x40/0x50
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x55/0xa0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x82/0xb0
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x40/0x80
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f32b84540ab
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Code: ff ff ff 85 c0 79 9b 49 c7 c4 ff ff ff ff 5b 5d 4c 89 e0 41 5c c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffdd87e5148 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffdd87e51a0 RCX: 00007f32b84540ab
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RDX: 00007ffdd87e51a0 RSI: 00000000c0306480 RDI: 000000000000000f
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RBP: 00000000c0306480 R08: 0000556e9a4293d0 R09: 0000000000000016
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000556e994bc7e0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R13: 000000000000000f R14: 00007ffdd87e51a0 R15: 0000000000003000
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Modules linked in: tun cdc_acm md4 nls_utf8 cifs dns_resolver fscache netfs libdes snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer dm_crypt trusted asn1_encoder xt_nat iptable_>
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  drm_ttm_helper ttm i2c_algo_bit mxm_wmi crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel wmi drm_kms_helper ghash_clmulni_intel cec drm r8169 video uas usb_sto>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: ---[ end trace 6a741c284e912584 ]---
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xac/0x220
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Code: aa 20 d1 44 49 8b 00 49 83 78 10 00 48 89 44 24 08 0f 84 43 01 00 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 3a 01 00 00 8b 4d 28 48 8b 7d 00 48 01 c1 <48> 8b 19 48 89 ce 48>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb7d901f3f700 EFLAGS: 00010206
13:43:57 Orion kernel: general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x108ddb743acd5eb1: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CPU: 4 PID: 2724 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 5.13.15-200.fc34.x86_64 #1
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8700/0KWVT8, BIOS A07 03/13/2014
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xac/0x220
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Code: aa 20 d1 44 49 8b 00 49 83 78 10 00 48 89 44 24 08 0f 84 43 01 00 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 3a 01 00 00 8b 4d 28 48 8b 7d 00 48 01 c1 <48> 8b 19 48 89 ce 48>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb7d901f3f700 EFLAGS: 00010206
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RAX: 108ddb743acd5e81 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 108ddb743acd5eb1
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RDX: 0000000000728bcf RSI: 0000000000000dc0 RDI: 00000000000300c0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RBP: ffff8dd200042600 R08: ffff8dd50ed300c0 R09: 0000000000000018
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R10: ffff8dd12d26f208 R11: ffffb7d901f3f988 R12: 0000000000000dc0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R13: ffff8dd200042600 R14: 0000000000003000 R15: ffffffffc06922ce
13:43:57 Orion kernel: FS:  00007f32b7bcea80(0000) GS:ffff8dd50ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CR2: 00007f32b778d000 CR3: 000000010984e003 CR4: 00000000001706e0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Call Trace:
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_mem_new_type+0xae/0x2a0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_umem_new+0x130/0x220 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_ioctl_new+0x129/0x1e0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_umem_search+0xe0/0xe0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0xdc/0x180 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvif_object_ctor+0x122/0x1c0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvif_mem_ctor_type+0xc2/0x180 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_ptes_get_map+0x2c/0x90 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_map+0x18d/0x350 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_mem_host+0xf3/0x190 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_sgdma_bind+0x30/0x80 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_bo_move+0x3c1/0x820 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? ttm_pool_type_take+0x7d/0x90 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? ttm_pool_alloc+0xe6/0x590 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x90/0x170 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_validate+0x11c/0x150 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_init_reserved+0x239/0x2c0 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ttm_bo_init+0x4a/0xc0 [ttm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nv10_bo_put_tile_region.isra.0+0x80/0x80 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_bo_init+0x7c/0x90 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nv10_bo_put_tile_region.isra.0+0x80/0x80 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nouveau_gem_new+0xf0/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_gem_new+0x7f/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_gem_ioctl_new+0x45/0xe0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nouveau_gem_new+0xf0/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0x86/0xd0 [drm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x220/0x3e0 [drm]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nouveau_gem_new+0xf0/0xf0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? __ia32_sys_timer_getoverrun+0x40/0x50
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x55/0xa0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x82/0xb0
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x40/0x80
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f32b84540ab
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Code: ff ff ff 85 c0 79 9b 49 c7 c4 ff ff ff ff 5b 5d 4c 89 e0 41 5c c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffdd87e5148 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffdd87e51a0 RCX: 00007f32b84540ab
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RDX: 00007ffdd87e51a0 RSI: 00000000c0306480 RDI: 000000000000000f
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RBP: 00000000c0306480 R08: 0000556e9a4293d0 R09: 0000000000000016
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000556e994bc7e0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R13: 000000000000000f R14: 00007ffdd87e51a0 R15: 0000000000003000
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Modules linked in: tun cdc_acm md4 nls_utf8 cifs dns_resolver fscache netfs libdes snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer dm_crypt trusted asn1_encoder xt_nat iptable_>
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  drm_ttm_helper ttm i2c_algo_bit mxm_wmi crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel wmi drm_kms_helper ghash_clmulni_intel cec drm r8169 video uas usb_sto>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: ---[ end trace 6a741c284e912584 ]---
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xac/0x220
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Code: aa 20 d1 44 49 8b 00 49 83 78 10 00 48 89 44 24 08 0f 84 43 01 00 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 3a 01 00 00 8b 4d 28 48 8b 7d 00 48 01 c1 <48> 8b 19 48 89 ce 48>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb7d901f3f700 EFLAGS: 00010206
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RAX: 108ddb743acd5e81 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 108ddb743acd5eb1
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RDX: 0000000000728bcf RSI: 0000000000000dc0 RDI: 00000000000300c0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RBP: ffff8dd200042600 R08: ffff8dd50ed300c0 R09: 0000000000000018
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R10: ffff8dd12d26f208 R11: ffffb7d901f3f988 R12: 0000000000000dc0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R13: ffff8dd200042600 R14: 0000000000003000 R15: ffffffffc06922ce
13:43:57 Orion kernel: FS:  00007f32b7bcea80(0000) GS:ffff8dd50ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CR2: 00007f32b778d000 CR3: 000000010984e003 CR4: 00000000001706e0
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb 4-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
13:44:32 Orion kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronizing SCSI cache
13:44:32 Orion kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb 4-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5580, bcdDevice= 0.10
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb 4-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb 4-5: Product: Extreme
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb 4-5: Manufacturer: SanDisk
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb 4-5: SerialNumber: AA010527142139551888
13:44:32 Orion kernel: usb-storage 4-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
13:44:32 Orion kernel: scsi host9: usb-storage 4-5:1.0
13:44:32 Orion mtp-probe[251591]: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-5"
13:44:32 Orion mtp-probe[251591]: bus: 4, device: 3 was not an MTP device
13:44:32 Orion mtp-probe[251597]: checking bus 4, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-5"
13:44:32 Orion mtp-probe[251597]: bus: 4, device: 3 was not an MTP device
13:44:33 Orion kernel: scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme          0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
13:44:33 Orion kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
13:44:33 Orion kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdn] 125045424 512-byte logical blocks: (64.0 GB/59.6 GiB)
13:44:33 Orion kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdn] Write Protect is off
13:44:33 Orion kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdn] Mode Sense: 33 00 00 08
13:44:33 Orion kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdn] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
13:44:33 Orion kernel:  sdn: sdn1 sdn2
13:44:33 Orion kernel: sd 9:0:0:0: [sdn] Attached SCSI disk
13:45:01 Orion CROND[251616]: (root) CMD ([[ "`pgrep -x each5min`" ]] || each5min >& /dev/console)
13:45:01 Orion CROND[251615]: (root) CMDEND ([[ "`pgrep -x each5min`" ]] || each5min >& /dev/console)
13:45:06 Orion sshd[251632]: rexec line 123: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation
13:45:06 Orion audit[251633]: CRYPTO_KEY_USER pid=251633 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=destroy kind=server fp=SHA256:ee:51:4b:d5:b0:6a:97:cd:fa:74:d8:>
13:45:06 Orion audit[251632]: CRYPTO_SESSION pid=251632 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=start direction=from-server cipher=aes256-gcm@openssh.com ksize=>
13:45:06 Orion audit[251632]: CRYPTO_SESSION pid=251632 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=kernel msg='op=start direction=from-client cipher=aes256-gcm@openssh.com ksize=>
13:45:06 Orion kernel: general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x108ddb743acd5eb1: 0000 [#2] SMP PTI
13:45:06 Orion kernel: CPU: 4 PID: 251632 Comm: sshd Tainted: G      D           5.13.15-200.fc34.x86_64 #1
13:45:06 Orion kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8700/0KWVT8, BIOS A07 03/13/2014
13:45:06 Orion kernel: RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0xc7/0x260
13:45:06 Orion kernel: Code: 05 de 1d d1 44 49 8b 00 49 83 78 10 00 48 89 04 24 0f 84 70 01 00 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 67 01 00 00 8b 4d 28 48 8b 7d 00 48 01 c1 <48> 8b 19 48 89 ce 48>
13:45:06 Orion kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb7d90d6a78c0 EFLAGS: 00010206
13:45:06 Orion kernel: RAX: 108ddb743acd5e81 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 108ddb743acd5eb1
13:45:06 Orion kernel: RDX: 0000000000728bcf RSI: 0000000000000d40 RDI: 00000000000300c0
13:45:06 Orion kernel: RBP: ffff8dd200042600 R08: ffff8dd50ed300c0 R09: 0000000000000002
13:45:06 Orion kernel: R10: 00000000002c4051 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000d40
13:45:06 Orion kernel: R13: 0000000000000060 R14: ffff8dd200042600 R15: ffffffffbb4003b1
13:45:06 Orion kernel: FS:  00007f77fe857900(0000) GS:ffff8dd50ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
13:45:06 Orion kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
13:45:06 Orion kernel: CR2: 00007f77ff4ed49f CR3: 000000010469c002 CR4: 00000000001706e0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x108ddb743acd5eb1: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CPU: 4 PID: 2724 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 5.13.15-200.fc34.x86_64 #1
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8700/0KWVT8, BIOS A07 03/13/2014
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xac/0x220
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Code: aa 20 d1 44 49 8b 00 49 83 78 10 00 48 89 44 24 08 0f 84 43 01 00 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 3a 01 00 00 8b 4d 28 48 8b 7d 00 48 01 c1 <48> 8b 19 48 89 ce 48>
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb7d901f3f700 EFLAGS: 00010206
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RAX: 108ddb743acd5e81 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 108ddb743acd5eb1
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RDX: 0000000000728bcf RSI: 0000000000000dc0 RDI: 00000000000300c0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: RBP: ffff8dd200042600 R08: ffff8dd50ed300c0 R09: 0000000000000018
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R10: ffff8dd12d26f208 R11: ffffb7d901f3f988 R12: 0000000000000dc0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: R13: ffff8dd200042600 R14: 0000000000003000 R15: ffffffffc06922ce
13:43:57 Orion kernel: FS:  00007f32b7bcea80(0000) GS:ffff8dd50ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
13:43:57 Orion kernel: CR2: 00007f32b778d000 CR3: 000000010984e003 CR4: 00000000001706e0
13:43:57 Orion kernel: Call Trace:
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_mem_new_type+0xae/0x2a0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_umem_new+0x130/0x220 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_ioctl_new+0x129/0x1e0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_umem_search+0xe0/0xe0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0xdc/0x180 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvif_object_ctor+0x122/0x1c0 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  nvif_mem_ctor_type+0xc2/0x180 [nouveau]
13:43:57 Orion kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_ptes_get_map+0x2c/0x90 [nouveau]
```

....

Comment: Please post `dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,warn` output, also check your `journalctl` messages before such freezes. The death of the SSH server might indicate a kernel panic e.g. caused by malfunctioning video drivers. If you encounter this issue once again, please check if the PC is at least pingable (make sure pings are allowed in firewall config).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: I added the output of `dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,warn` below the original question.

Comment: `[18457.872004] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[18458.761887] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[18458.762881] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[18459.919872] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1009 tx timeout` - these messages indicate something is very wrong but they alone are not enough.

Comment: I've experienced around 10 freezes in a couple of days. I'm afraid Studio is going to harm my computer. Freezing continues despite that I upgraded the whole system to the last Fedora 34. Last output of `dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,warn` added above.

Comment: I tried to run memtest86 after installing it with memtest-setup, but I got an frozen empty blue screen for 5 minutes without any info on it (is it like that??), until I gave up. Just to test allocation, I followed this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1368/149203 : The program consumed all RAM, and all swap, with everything full up to 24GB and counting... no problems. Studio is the only software I run that gives me this problem, even without running any other program (that I started myself). I am running Studio side by side with a console with kernel messages, let's see what happens...

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Another freeze while editing in Android Studio. Memory consumption was very low, no swap. Please see above the EDIT 4 for the kernel crash logs (journalctl).

Comment: Please install NVIDIA proprietary drivers. The crash is in `nouveau` (an open source driver for NVIDIA GPUs) which is not known to be stable enough.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Ok then I tried 4 things: Try 1: Following `https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/installing-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-34/14071` I tried with `dnf install akmod-nvidia` which installed 27 packages. Lots of problems and crashes. Try 2: Uninstalled `xorg-x11-drv-nouveau`, same problem. Try 3: Then I went to `https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/nvidia-auto-installer-for-fedora-now-works-with-fedora-34/13765`, and the auto installer only works with newer cards. Try 4: The instruction on NVIDIA site are so cumbersome that the chances of rendering the system unusable are way too high.

Comment: *Lots of problems and crashes* That's weird. I've been using proprietary NVIDIA drivers for two decades now with zero issues. Could you reveal what those problems and issues are? NVIDIA drivers are quite stable and used by hundreds of thousands of people.

Comment: Here's the correct proper guide how to install NVIDIA drivers: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA You can continue to use `nouveau` but considering its "stability" I'd try to install NVIDIA drivers instead.

Comment: Yes, that's the page I used. Even after waiting 10 minutes after installation, the command `modinfo -F version nvidia` keeps giving me `modinfo: ERROR: Module nvidia not found`. It shouldn't take this long to build the kmod. And it seems this is a common issue: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/nvidia-driver-not-working-after-fedora-33-install/9959

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I was able to install the new driver. If you follow the instructions on rpmfusion, it installs old driver 465 for the old kernel 5.13.15. But if you add repo `rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver`, it installs the new driver 470 for kernel 5.13.16. Today Rpmfusion is not working very well... Anyway, so far, no crashes.

Comment: I have no idea what happened, but my rpmfusion-nonfree-updates repo was disabled (did I ever have it enabled??). The 470 is here:

http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/updates/34/x86_64/a/

So probably I just had the rpmfusion-nonfree-updates disabled, didn’t find the new kernel-devel package, and thus failed to install the new driver.

Sorry, it was all my fault.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: after a week or so working with the NVidia drivers, crashes are finally gone and system is perfectly stable. So indeed (it seems) it was a nouveau issue. If you wish, you can post this as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install NVIDIA proprietary drivers. The crash is in `nouveau` (an open source driver for NVIDIA GPUs) which is not known to be stable enough.

Please consider filing a bug report: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/nouveau/-/issues/

Comment: After a week or so working with the NVidia drivers, crashes are finally gone and system is perfectly stable. So indeed (it seems) it was a nouveau issue. I actually already filled a bug report against Fedora kernel... with the usual absolute silence. I will change it to Nouveau. Thanks!

Comment: Ticket opened for nouveau: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/nouveau/-/issues/121

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Thank you for the bug report! Looks like it's actionable and will be fixed sooner or later. NVIDIA binary drivers are still the only option if you have a Pascal or later generation GPU because `nouveau` doesn't support power management for them due to NVIDIA unwilling to release the firmware. :-(